# JAXB and JPA - Two XML documents referring to the same object in a database

Tags: java, xml, jpa, jaxb

I'm using JAXB and JPA to create a web service that stores/serves up results of sports competitions. JAXB is used to un-marshal incoming XML files, the results of which are then stored in the database using JPA. Within a single XML file references are used to maintain referential integrity, ensuring that a single competitor is only stored in the database once (with all relevant references to that competitor pointing to their one record in the DB). This all works fine however if I then submit another XML document which contains some competitors that were present in the first XML document, an additional (duplicate, aside from ID which is auto-generated) entry is made to the database, whereas I would like references to be made to their original entry created as a result of the first XML document. For the purposes of my current implementation 'duplicate competitor' is defines by a duplicated surname, first name and nationality - I realise that this could lead to incorrect associations (e.g. to competitors both called John Smith from the UK) but I can live with those for now.

I'd appreciate someone pointing be in the right direction to solve this!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have JAXB unmarshalled Java objects that have duplicate values and thus there are duplicate queries fired by JPA.

Here are few solutions:
 1. Have a JPA specific object graph in DAO layer and copy the JAXB generated java object values to it. This will be more clean design and JPA and JAXB both can change in your project without changing others.
 2. Use duplicate removing options in JAXB like generate all the incoming XML to single package and avoid the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem - just needed a few more days at it...

In the function that persists object to the database, I'm now doing a lookup to see if there is an existing object in the database that matches the first name, surname and nationality of the competitor that we're about to persist and if so, it replaces the new object with the one already in the database, hence avoiding duplicates.